# Can we make use of the Sharp Architecture in a web application, without MVC?

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I am a newbie to NHibernate. Just was thinking whether we can make use of the Sharp Architecture in a web application, without MVC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you can use the repository/entity pattern without MVC.  We use Sharp in an MVC application as well as a counter part desktop application.

Just reference Sharp.Core and Sharp.Data.